# DOM ready in GWT

Tags: gwt, domready

Is there something like jquerys `ready()` in GWT. I add an iframe and will check when the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 4):

`document.ready()` is similar to the `onModuleLoad()` method in your GWT EntryPoint. They both execute, when the document is ready.

Comment: but i dont want to start a new app, I jsut want to see if the dom of the iframe is ready.

Comment: Well, I assumed, that your GWT code is in the iframe (so its onModuleLoad method will be called, when it's ready). I'm not sure, if the thing you want to do (waiting until the iframe is ready) is possible at all, as long as you can't run javascript from within the iframe. At least, I'm pretty sure, that this will not work reliably (also not with jQuery). There was a similar situation in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042139/gwt-easiest-way-to-do-a-simple-loading-screen-until-file-is-loaded/5044660#5044660), and it looks as if this doesn't work with Chrome.

Comment: It should be no problem in JavaScript. I can get the window object of  the iframe and add an event to it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe/205221#205221

Comment: You should really test this with Chrome. When I tried adding an `onload` attribute to an iframe, chrome (as opposed to all other browsers) always fired the event immediately, long before the entire content was loaded. (I made the server send the content very slowly, so this was clearly visible.)

Comment: its not about the onload event its about domcontentloaded I'm looking for

Answer (score 4):

You can create a [deferred command](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleDeferred%28com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.ScheduledCommand%29) to execute when the browser event loop returns.

```
boolean ready=false;
public void onModuleLoad() {
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            ready=true;
            Window.alert(ready+"");    
        }
    });
    for (int i=0;i<9999;i++){
        RootPanel.get().add(new Label(ready+""));
    }
}
```

This example places 9999 labels at DOM, only after then alerts true

Comment: Can you explain how this could help me find out if the domready is fired in an iframe?

Comment: I did not think the question was specifically about capturing domready event. Regarding your comment, I think you could use [javascript](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domready.shtml) to capture the event and  [JSNI](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#calling) to call a GWT method when the event fires

Comment: Sure I can do this JSNI, but the question was about a buildin solution in GWT.

Answer (score 0):

Not really: it isn't a paradigm that really translates well to Java. You might want to just include jQuery or Zepto and use the `ready` function from one of those.